# Display BLOB data from sqlite On Pyqt5 DESIGN

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, blob, qlabel

I have database include BLOB Column named (IMG)
What I need that when search by code, the item image displayed , but the result always be like that 
(caV\xd6\xf7\xd0\xec]c\x1b\x95\xe2\xa4\x00\xe3\xd3\x82L\xc9L\xa2W8H\xaf\xe4\xe0\x9f\xcb\x7f\xb5\xbautm]\x94\'\xb6\xb7p\xa7{\xbffU\xb7Q\xd5\x8d\xe3\xe1\xb....etc)

```
import io
import base64
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import ast
import sqlite3
import sys

class HmcProject ( QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow ):  # ,FORM_CLASS
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__ ( self )
        super ( HmcProject, self ).__init__ ()
        self.setupUi ( self )
        self.Handle_Buttons ()
        self.Db_Connect ()
        self.Image_Retrive()


    def Db_Connect(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect ( 'deals_db.db' )
        cursor = self.connection.cursor ()

    def Handle_Buttons(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Image_Retrive)


    def Image_Retrive(self):
        try:

            cursor = self.connection.cursor ()
            itemsearch = self.lineEdit_Item_NameS_3.text ()

            sql = ('''
            SELECT IMG  FROM deals_data 
            WHERE ITEM_CODE= ?
            ''')

            cursor.execute ( sql,[(itemsearch)])
            data = cursor.fetchone ()
            print ( data [0])
            pix= QPixmap.loadFromData(data[0])
            self.label.setPixmap(pix)

        except:
            pass

def main():
    app = QApplication ( sys.argv )
    window = HmcProject ()
    window.show ()
    app.exec_ ()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Comment: share deals_db.db

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uu4Re2eaMSQ1dwFbHt_cB1XDWYjpifXc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load the pixmap using [`loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1) as a static function, but it's not.
Also, that function returns a `bool`, reporting if the loading has been successful.

You have to create a new QPixmap instance first, then load the data, and finally show it in the label if it has been loaded:

```
    pix = QPixmap()
    if pix.loadFromData(data[0]):
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)
```

<sub>PS: avoid space characters around parentheses, they are unnecessary and distracting; also, don't confuse and mix calls on the base classes, in python3 it's enough to call `super().__init__()` just once,
 even for multiple inheritance classes</sub>

Comment: I don't know what to say!, Thanks a lot.. How to Adjust image size to fit Label Size

Comment: @hsmbarakat you can use `self.label.setScaledContents(True)`, but it will always ignore the aspect ratio of the original image. If you have a default maximum size you want to use, you can use [`QPixmap.scaled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled): `self.label.setPixmap(pix.scaled(self.defaultWidth, self.defaultHeight, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))`